# Module name redefines built-in

Tags: python, coding-style, naming-conventions, conventions

I'm making a game in Python, and it makes sense to have one of my modules named 'map'.  My preferred way of importing is to do this:

```
from mygame import map
```

As pylint is telling me, however, this is redefining a built-in.  What's the common way of dealing with this?  Here are the choices I can come up with:

1) Ignore the pylint warning since I don't use the built-in map anyway.

2) Change to:

```
import mygame
```

then reference as mygame.map throughout my code.

3) Rename my map module to something else (hexmap, gamemap, etc.)

I'm leaning towards (2) but I want to see what other people think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is subjective; there's no right answer.

That said, for me 3 is the only sensible option. Really *really* don't do 1; overwriting builtins is almost never a good idea and in this case it's especially confusing. 2 is better, but I think there is still an expectation that any function called `map` performs some operation similar to that of the builtin.

Maybe `mapping`?

Comment: I think `mapping` would be seen by the outsider as something to do with a data structure like a dictionary rather than a game map

Comment: That's the name of a module, not a function.  It contains classes for hex tiled maps, single hex tiles, helper functions, etc.

Comment: @Colin: sorry, edited. Why not `maps`? @Rafe: that's true; I think the context is sufficient in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Quoth [PEP 20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Explicit is better than implicit.
>   In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
>   There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

`mygame.map` is more explicit than `map`. `mygame.board` or `mygame.terrain` is less ambiguous than `mygame.map`. Guessing if code is talking about `__builtins__.map` or `mygame.map` is frightful and will mostly be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Options 2 or 3 would work, however I think it would be most understandable to rename `map` so that it can't be confused. That way, you can get the conciseness that referring to `map` instead of `mygame.map` gives you, but you won't have any problems with scope. Also, I think map is a somewhat undescriptive variable name, so it'd be better to give it a more specific name.